# build the following periodic source in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Anyone could suggest how to build the following periodic source in Simulink? The left part is sine wave

The period is 0.8 seconds. From 0 to 0.3 sec, it is a half sine function (positive half, period 0.6 sec) with amplitude 100; from 0.3 to 0.8, equal to 0

thanks:)

Comment: superpose sine- and cosine- source blocks together with the step generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the time and data vectors in the MATLAB Workspace such as

```
>> t = linspace(0,0.8,100)';
>> u = 100*sin(pi/0.3*t);
>> u(t>=0.3) = 0;
```

then in Simulink use the Repeating Sequence source block with time vector set to be variable t and data vector set to be variable u.